# How can I diagnose and speed up slow Linux puppet sync?

Tags: performance, puppet, puppetmaster

I'm running puppet and it functions okay, but it's taking about 15 minutes on a sync without any changes, and it seems to me that this shouldn't take more than a minute or two. Here are some stats:

- ping 40ms
- 49 files, 3 MB, largest is 90K
- master is Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) w/ puppet 2.7.11

  - (upgrading to puppet 2.7.23 didn't help)
- agent is Debian 7/64 w/ puppet version 2.7.23
- server is serving one client, only

I have tried with and without Apache tunnel/WEBrick/passenger with the same results.

What are some strategies for diagnosing this and and improving on the sync time?

**UPDATE:** In my case, in addition to the selected answer for using the `--evaltrace` option, I used `strace` and found that TCP connections were timing out and that my firewall was rate-limiting. (Why puppet didn't report the timeout and why it’s not reusing the connection, I don’t know.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most direct approach is running the `agent` with the `--evaltrace` flag like

```
puppet agent --test --evaltrace
```

This will give you a good idea of which resources are the most expensive.

For your large files, you may want to experiment with different [checksum](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-checksum) alternatives.

Comment: Cool! I wasn't aware of that flag.

Comment: Okay, so why is this so slow? It's only 12Kb. `/Stage[main]/Mailmxbackup/File[mailmxbackup-mailman-aliases.db]: Evaluated in 31.29 seconds`

Comment: Ugh, no clue. Is the inode of any directory in its path unusually large? (I.e., has the directory grown beyond usual proportions at some point)? That will slow down Linux file operations drastically.

Comment: Ack! I found it. Shorewall was rate-limiting. I edited the question to remove the unrelated symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Check : https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PA-3380 which describes slowness caused by a mix of SELinux and the number of mounts.

Nobody is picking this up, which is a shame, as most (enterprise) users will notice a speedup of at least 50%, and much less impact on system load